# Material UI Autocomplete: onChange is not triggered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

In my example of Material UI's Autocomplete I want to select an option via keyboard events:

- Browse through options with Up and Down arrow keys
- Select desired option with ENTER

Unfortunately, the `onChange` is not triggered.

https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-panna-xinkdw?file=/demo.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part in your causing `onChange()` not to trigger,
because of `setInput(option)`:

```js
const handleHighlightChange = (event, option, reason) => {
    if (option && reason === "keyboard") {
      setInput(option);
    }
};
```

You can just call `handleOnChange()` withtout the using the prop `onHighlightChange`

for example:

```js
export default function ComboBox() {
  const [input, setInput] = React.useState(null);

  const handleOnChange = (event, value, reason) => {
    if (reason === "selectOption") {
      window.location.href = value.url;
    }
  };

  const handleFilterOptions = (currentOptions) => currentOptions;

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      value={input}
      onChange={handleOnChange}
      options={top100Films}
      isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.label === value.label}
      includeInputInList={true}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
      filterOptions={handleFilterOptions}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: This also solves it somehow but I need to keep `onHighlightChange` for the effect that the keyboard-selected option is shown in the input.

Comment: I don't you need `onHighlightChange()`, all it does is `setInput()` which you can do in `handleOnChange()`

Comment: Well, this would remove the ability to move the selected option to the input when using the keyboard but I assume this is another issue I have to solve. Thanks anyway for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Try using onClose, as when you navigate with your keyboard your state value is updated to whatever is highlighted, so if you wanna trigger an event when user press ENTER, just use onClose, and it gives you pretty much same props as onChange

Comment: This would be a quick solution to this particular problem but it does not feel right.
`onClose` should not be used for listening to this kind of `change` event and could even result in side effects in later stages